# Caret difference between svmLinear and svmLinear2?

Tags: r, svm, r-caret

I can't seem to find the difference between svmLinear and svmLinear2 on the [following page](http://topepo.github.io/caret/Linear_Classifier.html).

What is the difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look on the [model list page](http://topepo.github.io/caret/modelList.html) you will see that the difference is which package the algorithm comes from.  In this case **svmLinear = kernlab** and **svmLinear2 = e1071**.  This is likely just for those who want to use the particular package's implementation.